# считывание из файла в конструктор

Tags: python, файлы, io

Изучаю python, и в задаче поднялся такой вопрос, что есть текстовый файл, первая строка это 5 параметров , которые используются для создания объекта, как их правильно считывать?
то есть есть такой файл
`Samoilov 13 300 500 USA`
`Mikhalenko 20 5000 100 Russia`
и каждое значение это отдельный параметр, который я буду передавать в конструктор
как сделать так, чтобы я считал данные для первого обьекта, затем перешел на вторую строчку, и считал из неё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://repl.it/repls/NervousForcefulDowngrade

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
        self.p4 = p4
        self.p5 = p5

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([self.p1, self.p2, self.p3, self.p4, self.p5])


with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        print(A(*row.split()))
```